# Too few arguments to function App\Exports\NilaiExport::__construct(), 0 passed in NilaiController.php on line 112 and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, laravel-excel

I want to export data to excel from $id, but an error occurred when I added the constructor in App/Export/NilaiExport. thanks

NilaiController.php

```
function download($id){

    return Excel::download(new NilaiExport, 'Nilai.xlsx');
    }
```

NilaiExport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Khs;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class NilaiExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return Khs::findOrFail($this->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it is `new NilaiExport($id)` And you should start to __understand__ what error text tells you.

Comment: I tried it but the page was not accessible ("Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.")

Comment: Probably you need to understand how to read an error message (and a bit of object-oriented programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function download($id){
    return Excel::download(new NilaiExport($id), 'Nilai.xlsx');
}
```

You need to pass through the `id` variable to the constructor method, it does say in the error message that it expects 1 parameter but you didn't supply one.

If the parameter is optional then the constructor signature should look something like this

```
public function __construct($id = null) {
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

and you would define `id` as

```
/**
 * @var \Illuminate\Support\Collection|null
 */
protected $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the constructor inside the NilaiExport class, but you do not pass the parameter class when creating the object, you can use the following code.
use blew

```
public $id;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->id = app()->make($id);
}
```

instead of this

```
public function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    }
```